# How to add SSH key to Gitlab-ce in Docker

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, gitlab

I am running Gitlab-ce V16.5.1 in a docker container. I need to add a proper SSH key to my profile in order to use HTTPS/SSH and to enable my pipelines to complete without generating HTTP Basic Access Denied errors.

The problem is: I can find no documentation on exactly how to do this. There are plenty of instructions for creating and installing SSH keys on Linux, Windows, and MacOS machines, but apparently, there is nothing on how to install a key in a docker container.

The problem isn't the addition of the private key to the account. That is well documented and the web interface makes it easy. What is not known is where to put the other key for the docker container. Where to place it on various other operating systems is well documented. It is, however, unknown where to place the key for a docker container.

There is some information on setting up SSH keys for Gitlab in Docker on Super- User, but that information is for Version 14 of Gitlab-ce and contains information that does not apply for Version 16. The instructions are ambiguous and even the name and location of the key file was deprecated in Version 14 and is probably inaccurate for version 16.

Can someone give some information on how to set up the server- side SSH key for Gitlab in Docker? Or can someone point me to a site with instructions that I may have missed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://medium.com/trabe/use-your-local-ssh-keys-inside-a-docker-container-ea1d117515dc)? Generally a Docker container is a Linux box. So you have to think of it that way. Or try `ssh -A` to pass/forward the SSH authentication credentials from one host to another during the SSH session.

Comment: I don't think these are viable solutions. The first would require that I rebuild the docker container for Gitlab-ce -- something that is not maintainable. The second requires that I *not* use docker as the executor for my pipelines -- but I have to use docker as the executor. There is supposed to be a way to create an SSH key for a Gitlab account. I just need to find out how to do it for Gitlab on docker.

Comment: I don't see how SSH keys relate to your problems. They would only be used by you yourself, when pushing to or fetching from a repo.  SSH keys are also entirely unrelated to HTTPS.

Comment: David: See https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-runner-no-access-to-private-repository-http-basic-access-denied/82118 and take a look at the solution to the issue described dated Jun 6. SSH keys are closely related to my problem.

Comment: The solution suggests enabling _SSL_ (TLS, really). This is a good idea. It still does not mean _SSH_ has anything to do with _SSL_. (Also make sure to properly @ people when replying, so they get a notification.)